# Wordpress Login Customization for External Authentication

Tags: wordpress, api, authentication

I'm not sure which approach is best but my situation is something need to tie the `admin login` with external source. I mean, WP normally is:

```
wp-admin ---> Check with WP Database ---> Authenticate
```

Now i need to put an additional tier, in between:

```
wp-admin ---> Check with WP Database ---> Check with External API (true/false) ---> Authenticate
```

Means, i need to put an additional Authentication Layer in between (similar logic like, we apply LDAP Authentication Module) which in this case is my own API in-between.

- So now in WP, where/which user/core file is handling the final `true/false` call returns in its traditional login concept?
- Where do i need to go and make the core hack or modification please?

Comment: You should probably change your question title to something like `Wordpress external auth plugin` or something. Using "hack" looks like you are trying to break someone's security.

Comment: okey done. can you now suggest please :)

Comment: Have you considered this: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/soap-authentication/ ? This also might be helpful, especially if you are comfortable with hacking source: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ldap-authentication-2/

Comment: first one is pretty interesting which i won't even need to hack the WP anymore. But does it mean my API must be SOAP/WSDL compliance?

Comment: If you want to use soap-auth untouched, I would say yes. But, you can create your own plugin based on this one, but instead of soap it could do something else to say yes or no to auth request

Comment: so then your suggestion would be, to make my own customizations based on that soap-auth module?

Comment: this is what I would do, if I could not be bothered to convert my external auth service to soap

Comment: okieee, pretty interesting ideas ^^ for either modify the own webservice to wsdl/soap compliance or modify the soap-auth module ;) (but anyway, sorry for still asking this, could you please point me out where is the native wp login core triggering work please? it could expend my view wider)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Wordpress SOAP Authentication plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/soap-authentication).

However, to make it work, you will need to convert your external auth service to be SOAP-compliant.

Alternatively, you can create your own WP plugin based on this one, but it would check your external source using something else than SOAP.